# Reset or Clear before appending an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It's my first app, I have been in tutorial hell for one year and decided to start my own little app.
So in this part Im using an addEventListener(),which appends and create text. The text is a variable created by the sum of the results of other functions (I don't know if this is relevant), but the thing is once I submit a button and creates the HTML element, if I keep submitting the elements will pile up. So I tried removeChild() but it didn't work because the variable was already created with its value, or...brought an error that can't removedChild() of undefined (since I tried to clear the values before appending), also tried to reseting the variable by adding a .innerHTML=""; but I don't know where to locate it. I also checked the replaceChild() but it didn't make sense, since everytime you click should be a new first event created. I tried the empty().append() but seems it's for jquery.

Seems that I need to learn a lot about scopes.

```
    let frase;
function armarPersonaje() { 
    if(!reversarNombre() || !descMes || !descDia){
        return false
    } else {
        frase = nombreReves + descMes + descDia;
        return true
    }
    
}


let div;
let h3Element;    
function mostrarPersonaje(){  

    let div = document.getElementById('container')
    let h3Element = document.createElement("h3")
    h3Element.className = "addedH3"

    if(frase.length > 0){

        h3Element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(frase));
        div.appendChild(h3Element)

    } 
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jalh.png)

Here's the complete code
https://jsfiddle.net/santiso/mzv3ct5e/

Comment: Do you want to limit the function run on multiple button clicks? You can use throttling

Comment: This little app consist in user input birth date and gives a result, so if you keep clicking should be same result, if inputs another date different result. Anyway the result should not replicate, should replace the previous one in spite of being the same. That's why I thought I needed to clear the result before creating it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here that in your last function `mostrarPersonaje()` you are always creating the element `h3Element` before the if , and even if you empty the parent node which is the `div` it will create a new element whit class `addedH3` the very next click !

How to fix it ? first do not create until you enter the condition , then delete it when ever you click again even before the condition

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HijenHek/a1r59gf3/12/)

and this is what i added

```js
    let oldH3Element =  document.querySelector('h3.addedH3')
    if(oldH3Element) oldH3Element.parentNode.removeChild(oldH3Element)
```

Comment: Oh I see it now! I tried that too, creating it after the condition but never occured to me to create  a new variable that grabs the previous element in order to delete IF exists! Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.